# What is the best thermal heatsink compound?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-technology

Re-worded
This is about the ***Experimental Physics*** not PC building or how to grease a car's radiator.

I have to insert a stainless steel enclosed PT100 into a block of metal to monitor its temperature to a milliKelvin. What is the best type of thermal grease to use? In this situation it does not matter if it is electrically conductive. Cost is also not an issue given the small amounts we will use. One possible constraint is that we may need to remove it at some point so we don't want it polymerizing or turning into an adhesive. Operating temperature from 0-100 degC

Comment: Is there an electrical engineering stack exchange? This is not really a physics question.

Comment: I am not interested in standard PC heatsink compounds. I am looking for extreme performance for a physics experiment.

Comment: useful meta links: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/797/520 and http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site, http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/experimental-physics-engineering http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268/questions-about-suppliers-for-basic-mechanical-parts-off-limits

Comment: Whatever the community consensus on this question is, we can migrate to [ee.se] if you don't get the answer you need here. I'm not sure how many regular users we have who might have experience in this areas. It is certainly outside of *my* ken.

Comment: If this is migrated, I would suggest migrating to the new Engineering SE instead of EE. This is a thermodynamics problem, which is really more an ME question than EE. (Although many EE's might also be able to answer).

Comment: The key to thermal grease is just using as little of it as possible and allowing as much direct contact between the two parts as possible. Grease is only there to fill the gaps caused by the roughness of the two surfaces.

Comment: I also think this would fit well on engineering.SE.

Comment: I closed this before seeing your comment, Dirk, and in light of that maybe I was too hasty to close it. I'll revisit this in a few hours and see what other comments have shown up, and perhaps reopen it at that time. But I wonder if it's clear from the question itself that this is for a physics experiment. (I don't really know, since I'm not an experimentalist.) I'm not saying the question _should_ be closed because of this, but I do think it would benefit from being more clear about the situation you're asking for.

Comment: Who else do you think would want to monitor a piece of metals temperature to within a milliKelvin? Certainly not PC builders. Does this group contain any experimental physicists or is it just armchair theoreticians?

Comment: I also note that nobody has mentioned Beryllium oxide, which rather points up the paucity of non-theoretical knowledge here.

Comment: (2 comments up) I suppose that's a good point. I think your title is throwing people off - while the question itself is valid, the title makes it sound like a PC repair question (and a very opinion-based one at that). Hence the flags. Anyway I'll reopen this. NB I'm not reopening because of the edit; as a matter of fact I think that is _not_ a good edit to make. It shouldn't be necessary to state outright that a question is about experimental physics. Would you mind if take a crack at clarifying the question, and then you can revert it if you don't like it?

Comment: What needs clarifying???? I want the best advice on a heatsink compound for milliKelvin temperature measurements. What else do you want me to add?

Answer (score 2):

The best performance (from a theoretical standpoint) would be to use diamond dust as a filler with something like silicone as a binder. In principle you can get about 5 times better thermal performance than you can with silver. Of course, you need the particle size as small as possible, which is harder to do with diamond than with silver (you can't precipitate diamond as nanoparticles like you can with silver).

Comment: This is really interesting. Do you have practical experience with such a mixture, or is this simply a theory (albeit a good one) to try? What about [Detonation Nanodiamonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detonation_nanodiamond)?

Answer (score 0):

[Beryllium Oxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium_oxide) - about 75% the conductivity of Copper

[Diamond dust](http://hackaday.com/2009/08/03/diamond-thermal-paste/)

[More on diamond thermal paste](http://www.overclockers.com/diamond-thermal-grease-testing/)

... and yes, [people do sell diamond loaded thermal paste](http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=TH-001-ID)

Now, does anyone sell diamond loaded Beryllia paste (ignoring it's toxic properties)?